# Pulling contents from a Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm builidng SHA1 signatures on files in [159251-TreeOfFunFiles](https://github.com/GiovanniMoretti/159251-directoryTreeOfFunFiles) with this function

```
def createFileSignature (filename):
    """CreateFileHash (file): create a signature for the specified file
    Returns a tuple containing three values:
    (the pathname of the file, its last modification time, SHA1 hash)
    """
    f = None
    signature = None
    try:
        filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)
        modTime = int(os.path.getmtime(filename))

        f = open(filename, "rb") # open for reading in binary mode
        hash = hashlib.sha1()
        s = f.read(16384)
        while (s):
            hash.update(s)
            s = f.read(16384)
            hashValue = hash.hexdigest()
            signature = (filename, modTime, hashValue)
    except IOError:
        signature = None
    except OSError:
        signature = None
    finally:
        if f:
            f.close()
            return (signature)
```

And I loop through each file using the `os.path` module in python.

```
        signatures = {}
        for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(directory):
            for f in filenames:
                file_path = dirpath + "\\" + f;
                if os.path.exists(file_path):
                    signatures[file_path] = sha.createFileSignature(file_path) #create a signature from the file
```

Which is just creating a `{}` dictionary of signatures.

```
        for key in signatures:
            if signatures[key] is not None:
                print signatures[key] #(doesnt really check against anything yet)
```

And this outputs  `('c:\\treeoffunfiles\\README.md', 1349709960, 'f430dc83251684703072a55eee0b0b6a2417c5e4')`, now my question is how can I retrieve the either the `2nd` or `3rd` element out of this dictionary? I've tried `print signatures[key][1]` but no luck

Comment: You should look into the `with open('filename') as f` syntax. It will greatly clean up your code.

Comment: Here is what your code would look like if you used it: http://pastebin.com/pFrEnimB

Comment: @NathanVillaescusa I'm not asking how to create a SHA1 value, I'm asking how can I pull elements out of a dictionary like I would out of a list.

Comment: I know, I answered your question below. I was just commenting on how you could reduce the lines of code. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should just be:

```
for key, value in signatures.iteritems():
    if value is not None:
        mod_time, hash = value[1:]
```